# has_many :through Association, NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "":String) and save association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through, nomethoderror

I can't get the has_many :through Association to work. And do I need to set something extra in the create method from the post_controller, to save also the post_category? (Below the code, the errors and my tries)

I have a has_many :through Association with post, post_category and as join table categorization as follows:

The Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :post_categories, :through => :categorizations
end
```

The Post::Category Model (Used namespacing for better project structure):

```
class Post::Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end
```

The Categorization Model (Used class_name, cause of the namespacing of Post::Category):

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :post_category, :class_name => 'Post::Category'
end
```

And then I have in the view a select where I create a post with a post_category:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :post_categories, :class => 'control-label', :value => 'Category: ' %>
  <%= f.select :post_categories, options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false' } %>
</div>
```

In the posts_controller, I permitted the `:post_categories` symbol:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_categories)
end
```

Here is my migration file for the Association:

```
class CreateCategorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :post_category_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :categorizations, :post_id
    add_index :categorizations, :post_category_id
    # multiple-key index enforces uniqueness on (post_id, post_category_id)
    # pairs, so that a category can't have the same post twice
    add_index :categorizations, [:post_id, :post_category_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

When I try to submit the form, I get the following error in the logs:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "3":String):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

So I searched for some answers ok -> [You can't assign string to association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706175/5327882).

I tried another way to make the association going to work.

So I tried using the post_category_id, like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082653/5327882)

I set in the select of the view

```
<%= f.select :post_category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false' } %>
```

then in the posts_controller permit the category_id:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_category_id)
end
```

and in the Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :post_category_id, :through => :categorizations
end
```

This is the new error:

```
Could not find the source association(s) "post_category_id" or :post_category_id in model Categorization. Try 'has_many :post_category_id, :through => :categorizations, :source => <name>'. Is it one of post or post_category?
```

Ok makes sense, cause there is no `post_category_id` association.

**Update:**

The post_params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"content"=>"content", "post_categories"=>"2"} permitted: true>
```

Comment: do you really expect this `has_many :post_category_id, :through => :categorizations` to work?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko It was a try, to show that I tried another approach. Yes but in the end it will definitely not work

Comment: could you add the params (from logs) from create action when you create post? (When having an initial setup)

Comment: yes, updated the question @AndreyDeineko

Comment: i meant along with the error. I wanted to see, what was passed - may be there we can find the source of error. So bigger piece of logs needed :)

Comment: sry maybe I understand you wrong. This is what I get in the logs

`Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rKM0Owc+uNDMlB63nPMa/nggszVffejp/YGJxkPldpTlJAzIhTGo3+LMuzmFAM2Ca3CProJVTAvkpbLgJRgNUw==", "post"=>{"post_categories"=>"2", "content"=>"film film"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a right solution for me with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/5327882) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253449/ruby-on-rails-4-select-multiple).

**First solution to just save one Post::Category with a Post**

Regarding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9917006/5327882), I had to change my permit parameter in the posts_controller to this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_category_ids)
end
```

Then I need also to change the select in the view where I create a post with a post_category to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :post_category_ids, :class => 'control-label', :value => 'Category: ' %>
  <%= f.select :post_category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false' } %>
</div>
```

That's it. The rest of the code is still the same as I showed before my second try in my question.

**Second solution to save multiple Post::Category with a Post**

Regarding to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253449/ruby-on-rails-4-select-multiple), I need to change my permit parameter in the posts_controller to this:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_category_ids => [])
end
```

And to select more than one Post::Category at the same time, I need to add `multiple: 'true'` to the select in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :post_category_ids, :class => 'control-label', :value => 'Category: ' %>
  <%= f.select :post_category_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false', multiple: 'true' } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
<%= f.select :post_categories, options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), {}, {class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false' } %>
```

to this:

```
  <%= f.select :post_categories[:id],
  options_from_collection_for_select(all_post_categories, :id, :name), 
  class: 'selectpicker', :'data-live-search' => 'true', required: 'false' , include_hidden: false} %>
```

Shoot me if I'm wrong.

Edited: include hidden:false for rails 4.2+ as per [SO 4585355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131675/rails-multiple-select-form-no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer)

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: try using 'post_categories[id]'

Comment: stil not working, `undefined local variable or method id`